# Google Sheets Query to extract data and replace checkboxes with values. (Diff)

Tags: mysql, performance, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my data set there are 4 columns:

| Column A | Reason |
| --- | --- |
| student D | ☑️ |
| student B | ◼️ |
| student A | ☑️ |

| Accuracy | Passed |
| --- | --- |
| ☑️ | ☑️ |
| ☑️ | ◼️ |
| ☑️ | ☑️ |

Column A has student Names; B,C,D has reason, accuracy and passed. The checkbox represents a value. Reason has 6 marks and Accuracy has 4 marks. A checkbox means they have been awarded these marks.

I want to extract this data using a query on Google sheets.
The data should look like student name, reason with marks, accuracy with marks and passed to show a pass or fail value.

I want to write a query on Google sheets for this solution.

I tried to use

```
-IFERROR( ARRAYFORMULA( IF( ((B2:B = "TRUE"), 6,IF ( C2:C = "TRUE"), 4, QUERY({Data})_ "SELECT * where Col1 IS NOT NULL)))),
"NA")
```

Here’s the link to the sheet with expected output. Thanks for your help.

I would appreciate a query based solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,arrayformula(hstack(A3:A,switch(--B3:B,1,6,0),switch(--C3:C,1,4,0),switch(--D3:D,1,"PASS","FAIL"))),
     query(Σ,"Where Col1!=''"))
```

[image]